# JavaScript неправильно считает ширину окна

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Здравствуйте, я новичок в JS, поэтому, возможно, вопрос покажется банальным, но я не могу понять, почему результаты арифметических вычислений в JS оказываются приближенными. Есть необходимость посчитать ширину окна и скроллбара, а затем при исчезании скроллбара сдвинуть блок влево на ширину скроллбара. В общем, есть код

```
var body_width = ($(window).width() / 2);
$('.head_text').css({'position': 'relative', 'left': - (getScrollbarWidth()/2)});
```

но результат в браузере оказывается не ожидаемым, блок дополнительно смещается ещё на несколько пикселей. С чем это может быть связано? Спасибо!

UPD:
Всем спасибо, всё оказалось проще, я не учёл изначальный сдвиг блоков, дело не в JS. Корректный вариант скрытия скроллбара без смещения контента у меня получилось реализовать следующим образом http://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/33pw51hc/7/
Буду благодарен за менее громоздкое и более изящное решение.

Comment: Нужна HTML разметка (самый минимум, чтобы можно было воспроизвести + тело функции  getScrollbarWidth(). Если вы решаете задачу с модальными окнами, то скорее всего вам нужен просто css.

Comment: Да, задача с модальными окнами (слайдер). К сожалению, в css я перепробовал почти всё, задача в том, чтобы у body скрывался скроллбар при появлении слайдера, но при этом сам блок не "дёргался", то есть контент оставался визуально на месте.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно проблема в методе getScrollbarWidth().

Если вы при вычислении ширины используете функцию:

```
var scrollWidth = div.offsetWidth - div.clientWidth;
```

Убедитесь, что у вашего элемента ("div") не указаны стилевые свойства "margin" и "padding".

Comment: Спасибо! Вы оказались правы) JS, вероятно, всё корректно считает, только вместо margin и padding у меня изначально в css был установлен сдвиг left: 19px, и когда скроллбар скрывался, нужно было к 'left': - (getScrollbarWidth()/2) прибавить те 19px

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вам и не нужен JS, если Вы используете bootstrap, а скорее всего это он. Проблема решается по разному, в зависимости от вашей HTML разметки, и CSS, вот одно из решений:

```
    body {
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    body.modal-open {
        overflow-y: scroll;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .modal {
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

P.S: Возможно это решение не подойдет лично Вам, но другим возможно.

Comment: Свой велосипед) Как я понял, Ваш вариант не убирает скроллбар, но решает проблему смещения. Однако есть вроятность, что будет появляться второй скроллбар, если окно не будет влезать по высоте. В моём случае вёрстка довольно специфична, нужно решить все эти проблемы. Возможно, Вы видели, модальные окна Вконтакте, второй скроллбар не появится, даже если изменится высота окна, но при этом при открытии модального окна и достаточной высоте скроллбар исчезает, а фон с контентом остаётся на месте. В принципе, у меня получилось решить проблему, но кода много http://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/33pw51hc/7/